# Form Navigation Item not showing to all users

Tags: forms, navigation, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a left hand form navigation item (NavBarItem) for the Contact Form.

```
<NavBarItem Id="navLink{a9b44918-671d-9ed7-5266-721c87b25297}" Sequence="10" Area="Info" Icon="$webresource:ft_CKYC16" Url="$webresource:ft_/ContactSummary">
    <Titles>
       <Title LCID="1033" Text="Client Summary" />
    </Titles>
 </NavBarItem>
```

This item shows a web resource and works fine when viewed as an admin user.

However, when viewed as a normal user the navigation item is not displayed.

This is probably a permissions issue.

Can anybody point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was indeed a security setting.

see the below article.

http://orwin.ca/2011/11/09/crm-2011-left-navigation-label-changes-not-visible-by-users/

cheers

Simon

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you added the link via Form customization screen then selected Navigation > Insert > Navigation Link. I'm not sure there is any other supported method anyway, but worth me checking.

If this is true, check that:

- The change (i.e. the contact entity and your web resource) is published
- The user has at least Read permissions on the Web Resource entity (Settings > Admin > Security Roles > Customization tab > Web Resource)