# Nav Bar on form issue

Tags: forms, navigation, dynamics-crm-2011

I am having an issue with a custom nav bar item in a form that links to a simple html web resource, for some reason the nav item is only visible to system admins, when I try to view the form with a regular user the nav item is not visible. Is there a privilege somewhere that I am missing? The nav item is in the common section of the form and it links to a web resource in CRM, I already tested and the resource is accessible to the users that cannot see the Nav item.

Comment: By Nav Bar do you mean the Ribbon?

Comment: If anyone else has this problem, after searching for a while I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848662/form-navigation-item-not-showing-to-all-users

Answer (score 1):

Download the sitemapeditor from codeplex. You probably need to give certain user rigths to do this. Using the sitemapeditor makes it that you can see how to do this by checking other nodes in the tree. Succes